# Rotate 3D model to obtain 2D Images

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a 3D model named model.obj

I was wondering if there is any python library to open a 3D model, rotate it and create PNG image of that model from that angle.
[image]

Comment: probably many. On the top of my head [Open3D](http://open3d.org) can do that, but it is probably a bit overkill :)

Comment: I am really new to Open3D. I have tried with the help of documentation but have not gotten any far. Can you suggest to me some examples?

Comment: 1. Load the mesh from your `.obj` file [function in docs](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.read_triangle_mesh.html)
2. Rotate the mesh [function in docs](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.rotate)
3. Visualize your result. This can be done manually, by opening the visualizer and moving the camera (which would also save you the rotation), or via headless rendering. Everthing is explained in detail here: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/visualization/index.html

Comment: However: since you already have tagged `opencv`: If you have your mesh data as a vertex-matrix and already have a way of rendering it would be much easier to simply multiply your vertices with a rotation matrix, I guess.

Comment: "how to display a mesh". without anything else, you could use OpenGL/Vulkan/D3D and draw this model yourself. there's a ton of game engines and visualization libraries (vtk, Open3D, ...) that use OGL/Vulkan/D3D. as far as I know, OpenCV has several modules that use such libraries and that can handle mesh data.